# CalendarView ação botão avançar e voltar

Tags: java, android, sdk

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca Calendarview

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

E o pessoal lá anda meio que sem comunicação, por isso vou perguntar aqui.

> Gostaria de fazer alguma ação quando mudar de mês, por exemplo
>   aparecer as datas marcadas apenas do mês atual quando clicar no botão
>   avançar ou voltar.

Não gostaria de alterar a biblioteca original, por isso estou achando complicado pegar o clique do botão.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

Tem uma função na biblioteca que verifica o mês que está, então ajudou.

```
public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {

}
```